# Cannot use publish_stream permission - Facebook SDK for Android 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList(permissions)));
```

I get this error when trying to pass "publish_permission" to setPermission as above. Why? How to fix? Where are you Facebook developers?

```
com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot pass a publish permission (publish_stream) to a request for read authorization
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the error message states you are trying to open a `read` session with a `publish` permission. Since SDK 3.0 you have to distinguish between read and publish actions, so if you want to use `publish_stream` you have to call `session.openForPublish(` or `session.reauthorizeForPublish(` after your first request.

Comment: Yeah, they changed a lot with SDK 3.0, I guess to harmonize it with the iOS SDK with iOS6 support.