# Facebook Login failed

Tags: android, facebook

I have a problem. I can bring name, gender(public profile). but I can't bring user_birthday ,email, offline_access.

Problem is as follow.

Should not pass a read permission (user_birthday) to a request for publish or manage authorization.
Should not pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish or manage authorization.
Should not pass a read permission (offline_access) to a request for publish or manage authorization.

request and bring Facebook data source

```
 try{

           json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
           uuserName = json.getString("name");
           userSex = json.getString("gender");
           userBirth = json.getString("user_birthday");            
           userEmail = json.getString("email");

       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

login source

```
String[] sPermissions = {"user_birthday", "email", "offline_access"};
mFacebook.authorize(this, sPermissions, new AuthorizeListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
  userBirth = json.getString("birthday");
```

Answer (score 0):

The messages that you are getting are **warnings** and not errors.

It is happening becuase you are using the Facebook Android SDK 2.0 , which has been made deprecated after the release of SDK v3.0.

In the latest SDK, `Util` class is no longer used in the same way and permissions are requested in a different manner.

`Facebook.request("me")` has also become deprecated as now all the data can be fetched on user login using `widget.Facebook.loginButton`.

Try and go through the documentation of the updated SDK and the warnings should stop bothering you.

And coming to the actual problem why you are not able to get the birthday is because of the wrong parameter you are trying to access in the JSON data.

You need to use `json.getString("birthday")`, according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Comment: i get the same warning messages and when i try to run it on nexus 5 and Samsung note the login process doesn't work. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Any messages on the log? I mean, it's very difficult to speculate anything without the logs.

Comment: a have added the log to your answer you can remove it later.

Comment: Try to call session.openForPublish(..)

Comment: could you link some code because my application is quite complex and the fix that i need to make do with session.openForPublish(..), im unable to understand this.

Comment: Something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598045/cannot-use-publish-stream-permission-facebook-sdk-for-android-3-0 ?

Comment: the exact problem is i am unable to initialize the session variable, gives me a null pointer

Comment: Oh, the log that you gave me had some other warning. Anyway, could you post a fresh question with the details and give me the link here ?

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215610/facebook-login-in-andorid-with-different-devices